# Android how to get notification from own server, own service

Tags: android, notifications, chat

I am writing the app that can chat with other. I saw some project : Parse, GCM,... It is exactly good. But I need to know how it work. Because want to use my own.

In my case, I saw when other send his chat, then it's almost display on my screen after 1-2 seconds. Then I think what happened:

1. My friend post his chat to server, and server send request to app with ID ( unique).
2. In my app, there have a service, which send request to this server each 1 second to get new chat, or notification. If found, display in my device.

Is my above ideal true? I am going to write about chat with client-server.

Give me reason why down vote.
 Thanks :)

Comment: Send request each second is very inefficient. Most chat app's uses XMPP/Jabber protocol. You can setup an XMPP server using OpenFire (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/), for instance. And use Smack (https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) framework to implement the client

Answer (score 1):

> In my app, there have a service, which send request to this server each 1 second to get new chat, or notification. If found, display in my device.

Implement as you say lead to energy(own app services use)/IO(every net request each 1 second)/server(large amount request from clients, and most of request is useless because nobody chat in 24h) waste, and message may lost or can't get notification in time if the service is killed by system(or don't start).

However, your method will work if you find a way to keep your service always alive, and make well design for servers to support large amount requests from large multi clients.

For the better, you can use dynamic look-up algorithm that keep a long interval if there is no notification recently.